# Retrieving email over SSL in Foxpro

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I'm trying to retrieve emails from a pop box over SSL, using Foxpro. Does anyone have any examples of code using OpenSSL, or have any other recommendations for how to do it? I've done my own research but not found any great answers.

Answer (score 2):

There's an example Visual FoxPro POP retrieval class [here](https://www.example-code.com/foxpro/pop3_ssl.asp) that uses the Windows Sockets library and SSL/TLS. It requires the Chilkat mail ActiveX control though.

Comment: Thanks Alan, I think I'm going to struggle to get the budget for the Chilkat ActiveX control.